# Django model field with database column

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to add a field to a Django object with the related database column. Just adding an attribute will work if a set the attribute after initializing the model, but as usual, I'm trying to get it to work the Django way.

```
class Stuff(models.Model):
    id = fields.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    log_user = None
```

This will work without any problems.

```
stuff = Stuff()
stuff.log_user = current_user
```

This doesn't

```
stuff = Stuff(log_user=current_user)
TypeError: 'log_user' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Is there any way to have the field behave the Django way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor will work if you do:

```
class Stuff(models.Model):

    id = fields.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    log_user = None

    def __init__(self, log_user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Stuff, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.log_user = log_user
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks. Just wish there was a meta_field in Django, so we don't have to jump through hoops to do something this simple.

Answer (score 1):

You need [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) here.

```
class Stuff(models.Model):
    id = fields.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    log_user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will still create a db column.

Answer (score 0):

```
Django recommend to use as a Foreign key Concept:

class Stuff(models.Model):
    id = fields.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    log_user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True, null=True)

while saving your Data you can add log_user object:
     Stuff = Stuff()
     stuff.log_user = user
     stuff.save()
```